# Assign Model property value from JavaScript value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model with the following definition:

```
namespace ESimSolChemical.Models
{

    public class Employee
    {        
        public int EmployeeID{ get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName{ get; set; }
        public string Age{ get; set; }
        public string Address{ get; set; }

    }
```

I have Following JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnEmployeePiker').click(function () {
            var oParameter = new Object();
            oParameter.MultipleReturn = false;
            var oReturnObject = window.showModalDialog('/Employee/EmployeePiker/', oParameter, 'dialogHeight:470px;dialogWidth:550px;dialogLeft:400;dialogTop:100;center:yes;resizable:no;status:no;scroll:no');           
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Javascript `oReturnObject` contains two property Like :

```
oReturnObject.EmployeeID;
oReturnObject.EmployeeName;
```

Now I would like to assign:

```
@Model.employeeID=  oReturnObject.EmployeeID;
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot set server side values with Javascript. You could bind these values to input fields like textboxes or hidden fields and then use Javascript to modify these values of these input fields.

Take a look at these articles, it might help you out:

- [Setting property on the model object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181151/setting-property-on-the-model-object)
- [get value from @Model inside jquery script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770578/get-value-from-model-inside-jquery-script)

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a server-side code like that in JavaScript.

You need to somehow post the updated values back to the server to process them.

Take a look at [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/), it makes things like this very easy. Basically, you will just serialize your model class on the client side to a JavaScript object, work with it until you decide to save it back and then you send it to the server as JSON, which will allow you to have an action method like this

```
public ActionResult UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    // Update the database...
    //
}
```

The page linked above has plenty of tutorials to start with.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used:

```
@{
   @Convert.ToString("var refID = " + @Model.RefID + ";alert(refID);")
}
```

and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are going to assign values of the model(server-side) through JavaScript (Client-side). This is not the correct way to update the server-side Model object from client-side code. Client-side JavaScript runs on the user's browser, while the server-side Model object is stored on the server. Therefore, you need to use some kind of communication between the client and server to update the server-side Model object.
like AJAX.

you can refer : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-ajax-call-from-javascript/ for ajax